# Creating complex JSON nesting of objects and arrays in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

My table looks like this:

[image]

I need to create JSON object with this structure:

```
    array=[
  {
    id: 2,
    items: [
      {
        id: 12
      },
      {
        id: 13
      },
      {
        id: 14
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    items: [
      {
        id: 15
      },
      {
        id: 16
      },
      {
        id: 17
      },
      {
        id: 18
      },
      {
        id: 19
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    items: [
      {
        id: 20
      },
      {
        id: 21
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    items: [
      {
        id: 22
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

So, in object must be parent's ID and in its items must be child's ID. Which query must I use and how can I create similar structure? Also it depands on order of these objects. Parents and children must be ordered. I mean, that in my query must be smth like this:

```
ORDER BY `order` ASC
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show your code first.

Comment: should be easier to build your JSON string from your data source rather than from that table.

Comment: Better to use nested foreach loop and create a multidimensional array then json_encode that

Answer (score 0):

Self Join may be the solution for this job. Try something like

```
SELECT  a.ID, b.ParentID FROM tester a, tester b WHERE a.ID = b.ID order by a.Order ASC
```